# Active Directory password complexity based onto entropy

Tags: password-policy, active-directory

I am evaluating the possibility to enable password complexity rules into my Active Directory, but the rules it offers are for me not good. So I would like to have a complexity rule based onto only two factors:

1. password length: at least 12/14/16 chars
2. a good entropy

Is it possibile to improve AD with this kind of rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You would need to create a custom Password Filter, but it's not a point and click function. See this Microsoft article on how to do so: [Custom Password Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721884(VS.85).aspx)

There are also a number of third party password filters available that may make it easier for you (e.g. NFront, SpecOps, etc.)